# How can I set some colors that take the dark/ light mode toggle into account?

Tags: xaml, winui-3, winui

I created a WinUI 3 project with a template. It offers the ability to switch between dark and light modes with the use of `ElementTheme.Dark`/`ElementTheme.Light`. How can I, for example, set a slightly different background color to a `StackPanel` than the `StackPanel` that surrounds it, without always taking the toggle into account with extra code? For instance, I tried

```xml
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColorLight2}">
```

but that does not change its color in dark mode.

Comment: You mean, you want to have ``StackPanel`` that doesn't change its ``Background`` when the theme is switched?

Comment: I want to define a background color for component x that automatically adopts its color for dark and light mode.

Comment: WinUI 2 or 3? C++ or C#? Please tag proper versions

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `ThemeResource`, let's say *CustomStackPanelBackground*.

For example, in `App.xaml` for the entire app:

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/FontSizes.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Thickness.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/TextBlocks.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                        <SolidColorBrush
                            x:Key="CustomBackground"
                            Color="HotPink" />
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                        <SolidColorBrush
                            x:Key="CustomBackground"
                            Color="SkyBlue" />
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

or if you just want to use it within a `Page`:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="CustomBackground"
                    Color="LightGreen" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="CustomBackground"
                    Color="SkyBlue" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

and actually use it like this:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource CustomBackground}">
...
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define [Theme-dependent brushes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-theme-resources#theme-dependent-brushes). By defining the same name in both "Light" and "Dark" resource dictionaries,

> when this brush is applied to a XAML element, its color is determined
> at run-time by the current theme, as shown in this table.

For example, [microsoft-ui-xaml/dev/NavigationView
/NavigationView_rs1_themeresources_v1.xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/4cbade6959cda4fca42a299fb540adc2f99c1e8a/dev/NavigationView/NavigationView_rs1_themeresources_v1.xaml#L13).